# How to make BeautifulSoup detects an li in ul?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[image: HTML code]

So i'm creating a bot that check the comments section of a certain website and update me on what is posted there. I tried using BeautifulSoup and wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = input("Please insert your link: ")
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
if page.status_code == int(200):
   print("Successful!")
else:
   print("Not successful!")
   print("Please restart this program!")
print(soup.find_all('div', class_='guestbook-body'))
```

as a test.
but what i got was:

```
Successful!
[]
```

I tried using soup.prettify and copied the html code on to a note pad to see what's wrong and it didn't detect the li tag un the ul :[The soup.prettify code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvGgZ.png)

I've been researching about the problem but I hit a dead end, if you have a solution to this problem please reply to this question.

Comment: let's see your page content returned by the request and a sub html that you want to process

Comment: the url would be useful

Comment: Are you sure the DIVs you want are in the page source? If BS isn't finding them, they might be added by JavaScript. Use `View Source` to see the page source before JS updates the DOM.